# bundle not found via ssh

Tags: ssh, bundler

If I ssh into my VPS as the deployment user and run `bundle -v` I get `Bundler version 1.1.5` as expected.

If I run `ssh deployment@123.123.123.123 bundle -v`, then I see `bash: bundle: command not found`

Why isn't bundle being shown running commands via ssh?

**More Info**

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc

# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run:

```
ssh deployment@123.123.123.123
```

You get a login shell on the remote host, which means that your shell will run (...for bash...) `.bash_profile` or `.profile` or equivalent AS WELL AS your per-shell initialization file.

When you run:

```
ssh deployment@123.123.123.123 some_command
```

This does not start a login shell, so it only runs the per-shell initialization file (e.g., `.bashrc`).

The problem you've described typically means that you need something in your `.profile` file (typically an environment variable setting) for everything to work.